# Why are my Applescript scripts executing in ScriptEditor but not as an application?

Tags: applescript

Applescript scripts execute in ScriptEditor but not as an application.

I have been playing with AppleScript for a few years and have not run into this situation until recently.

The following code example reflects my situation. I enter this code into ScriptEditor and it runs fine. The dialog box displays when a Safari window is visible and a MacOS alert is displayed when the window is not visible.

```
set appName to “Safari”
tell application "System Events"
    set winPos to position of first window of process appName
    display dialog "Test was successful”
end tell
```

I exported the code as an application named “test” then ran the app. The initial run prompted me to enter the app name into the Accessibility list in the Privacy & Security section of System Settings. Once done I ran the app again and was presented with this error…
￼

```
"test is not allowed assistive access.
System Events got an error: test is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrKZR.png)

The same error is displayed with and without the Safari window being visible.
I then commented out the “set winPos…” line and exported as app again. The app executed without errors.

Further testing resulted in the discovery that any code which attempted to perform a System Event action within a System Events tell worked well in the editor but triggered an error when compiled into an app.

I am running Sonoma 14.3.1 on a MacBook Air M1. Error occurs in safe mode as well as regular mode. I also ran the test on a barebones MacOS Sonoma VM using both UTM and Parallels 19; both in and out of safe mode.

Also tested on my older MacBook Pro Intel running Catalina. The app ran successfully indicating it may be an M1 issue.

Suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly as the error message says. Nowadays (Sonoma) you must grant the applet the needed access permissions.

Comment: Please re-read the error message. "… **assistive access**" As an aside, why not just get the windows from safari rather than system events?

Comment: Access permission and assistive access was granted. Also, the code listed is just an example, I get this error with all System Events actions.

Comment: You need permission to drive System Events.

Comment: matt, Thanks for the explanation answer below. I followed your steps and resolved this basic issue. I have been playing around with AppleScript for a few years and never had this issue until Sonoma.

Comment: The way to thank me is to accept my answer, completing the Question / Answer cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the app that runs is not the same app that you gave permission to. You keep changing it, either by editing it or just by running it.

So do this. If you have your applet already listed in Privacy & Security > Accessibility, delete its listing there. Throw away the original applet too, just to be on the safe side. From Script Editor, export your script using a different name, as an application, *run-only,* signed to run locally. Making it run-only will prevent the app from being self-modifying (maintaining any state) over the long term.

Now add *this* version of the applet to Privacy & Security > Accessibility. Make sure the switch is On. Double-click the applet in the Finder to run it. The run succeeds.

[image]